Calcular tamaño proporcional de fuente en imágenes de diferentes resoluciones
Estoy agregando texto como marca de agua a imágenes que subo a mi servidor.
El problema que tengo es que el texto varía de tamaño haciéndose más pequeño cuando la resolución de la imagen es mayor. Así por ejemplo, mi texto se ve bien en una resolución HD(1280 * 720), pero cuando subo una imagen en 4K(3840 × 2160) el texto queda muy pequeño y no se puede leer claramente.
Estoy trabajando con imágenes en HD, FullHD, 2K y 4K.
Alguien conoce de alguna proporción matemática o método que pueda aplicar donde el tamaño de fuente vaya aumentado de acuerdo al incremento de la resolución de la imagen pudiendo leer y distinguirse el texto sin ninguna dificultad?
Este es mi código:
$font_size = 28;
$text_position_x = 20;
$text_position_y = 20;
$text_color= imagecolorallocate($imagen, 25, 97, 54);
$font = 'fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf';
$text = 'miwebsite.com/';

imagettftext($imagen, $font_size, 0, $text_position_x, $text_position_y, $text_color, $font, $text);

Repito, para imágenes en HD aplico la fuente de 28 donde todo se ve muy bien, sin embargo para imágenes en FullHD, 2K y 4K el texto se ve muy pequeño y necesito un tamaño mayor que sea proporcional en tales casos y pueda leerse el texto o marca de agua.
Uso PHP como lenguaje backend.
Gracias por anticipado por sus sugerencias.

Necesitas de un factor para mantener la proporcionalidad. Para ello puedes utilizar el ancho de la imagen, que PHP se puede obtener con imagesx
Ya que tu indicas que se ve bien en un ancho de 1280 y todos los demás valores están ajustados a esa dimensión, pues dividides el ancho de la imagen por 1280 para obtener el factor.
$factor = imagesx($imagen) / 1280; 

$font_size = 28 * $factor;
$text_position_x = round(20 * $factor);
$text_position_y = round(20 * $factor);


Muchísimas gracias! Me sirvió totalmente tu respuesta :)
